# how to remote download a file using multi-part downloading?

Tags: php, multipart

i want to **download** a remote file on internet to my host.
but i want to download it with multi-part downloading to make it download faster.
just the same as ***download managers***.

Comment: PHP is not a multi-threaded language. So even you download by multi-part it'll be sequential. Unless you fork multiple process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `Range` header while requesting.

Sending `Range: bytes=500-999` will download the bytes form 500 to 999;

Note: PHP is *not* a multi-threaded language. So even you download by multi-part it'll be sequential. Unless you **fork** multiple process. Though using third-party extensions like curl you can do this through [`curl_multi_exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php)

Answer (score 2):

This will be dependent on the server that you are downloading from supporting Range Requests. Read up on [Range Requests](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html), and combine this with a multi-threaded [cURL](http://semlabs.co.uk/journal/object-oriented-curl-class-with-multi-threading), and you'll be able to have more than one download stream working at a time.